# Problem with onCreateDialog in Fragment class

Tags: android, fragment

I am getting an error when i use this method

`protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id){
        switch(id){
        case DATE_PICKER_DIALOG:
            return showDatePicker();
        case TIME_PICKER_DIALOG:
            return shoeTimePicker();
        }
        return super.`
As you can see the return statement gives me a syntax error every time i do `return super.onCreateDialog(id);`. Is it another way i am suppose to use this?

Also when i implement showDialog(). it gives me syntax

Does anyone know??

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`DialogFragment`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html).

Comment: could you proved an example of how to do this with a DatePicker? and ge the information once its set?

Comment: `DialogFragment` is trivial to use. Here is a project that uses one: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Honeycomb/FeedFragments